# html form required attribute field

Tags: html, required

My form is not honoring the `required` attribute of the "comments" field. I want it so that when the user submits the form, it shows "please fill the field", but instead the user can submit the form straight away.

```
<form class="form-part" method="post" action="contact_form.php" name="contactform" id="contactform" onSubmit="return checkForm1();">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" size="30" title="Name" required>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30" title="Email" required>
    <textarea rows="3" id="comments" name="comments" cols="40" title="Tell us what you think!" required></textarea>   
    <input type="submit"  name="Submit" alt="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Please include source for checkForm1 JavaScript reference.

Comment: It seems to be working fine when I run your code. See my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/haquja/edit?html,output)

Comment: What browser are you running?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple check function might be:

```
function checkForm1(frm){
  if (frm.comments.value==''){
    alert('Please leave a comment.' );
    return false;
  else return true;
}
```

For this to work you need to augment your form tag to:

```
<form ... onsubmitt="return checkForm1(this)">
```

Comment: It took some rereading, but I'm convinced the OP is trying to get the little native HTML5 popup that says "Please fill out this field."

Comment: @Drakes Yes, if that is the case then my post is just a reminder of the "good ole days" before HTML5 ... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

In your code Remove required from  Tag

```
<form class="form-part" method="post" action="contact_form.php"  name="contactform" id="contactform">
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30" title="Email" required>

<textarea rows="3" id="comments" name="comments" cols="40" title="Tell us what you think!" required></textarea>

  <input type="submit"  name="Submit" alt="Send" onSubmit="return checkForm1();">
</form>
```

and now run. and tell me form show or not.